# Differential Amplifier with the same entrance in both inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

So, I'm supposed to find an equation that relates the output and input of an OpAmp. For both zero and first order. The circuit is the one in the image, it should be easy, since it's a Differential configuration. But both entrances of the OpAmp are receiving the same voltage signal and this gave me a little bit of confusion, because I don't know if I could use the same steps of the normal Differential configuration.[image]

Comment: `But both entrances of the OpAmp are receiving the same voltage signal...` The op-amp, with the help of the negative feedback, will try to keep inverting and non-inverting input voltages equal. `... and this gave me a little bit of confusion` The `ve` input signal has its own reference (its negative end) but you can name the + and – voltages w.r.t. ground e.g. `vep` and `ven`, respectively. This way, the input signal will be \$v_e=v_{ep}-v_{en}\$ and the differential amplifier will take two inputs `vep` and `ven` so it'll be easier to work out.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for the tip, it makes sense. I did not think about this during my analysis, appreciate it.